# How to play Video from (iPhone - Local Storage) Using HTML?

Tags: html, ios, html5-canvas, cordova-plugins

*url = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/80B8A356-D56B-41ED-93A9-643DD66950F3/Library/Caches/temp.mp4"*

```
var defaultVideoElement = angular.element("<video id='mp4VideoContentStream' width='100%' height='100%' controls autoplay>" +
                                    "<source src='" + url + "'  type='video/mp4'/></video>");
```

Comment: Try to add some more code and what is the error you are facing?

Comment: I m not get any error. Video is not playing.